# Autodesk Revit: IfcGUID for Rooms changes every time

Tags: autodesk, revit-api, ifc

When I export an IFC from Revit, the IfcGuid parameter for rooms keeps changing with each export.

In my search I came across this github issue [1].

However, I still have the same problem that the IfcGuid for a room changes with each export.

Referring to the IFC file, it contains the following header

HEADER;
FILE_DESCRIPTION(('ViewDefinition [CoordinationView_V2.0, QuantityTakeOffAddOnView]'),'2;1');
FILE_NAME('7000-BS11','2023-12-03T13:13:22+01:00',(''),(''),'ODA SDAI 22.12','23.0.11.19 - Exporter 23.0.11.19 - Alternative UI 23.0.11.19','');
FILE_SCHEMA(('IFC2X3'));
ENDSEC;`

It looks like I'm running v23, which should have fixed this (according to github), but it didn't.

I am using Revit 2023.

[1] https://github.com/Autodesk/revit-ifc/issues/521

Comment: I suggest you raise this question directly in the [Revit IFC discussion forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/ifcexporter/discussion/general).